# Problema em Somar Varios Inputs

Tags: javascript, html

Poderiam por gentileza me ajudar?

Estou tentando fazer uma função que some vários inputs, porém ao invés de somar está concatenando.

**HMTL**

```
<form class="nacional">
    <input class="soma-nacional" value="5">
    <input class="soma-nacional" value="3">
    <input class="soma-nacional" value="2">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var nacional = document.querySelectorAll(".soma-nacional");
var somaNacional = [];

function somatoriaNacional(){
    var soma = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < nacional.length; i++){
        soma += parseInt(nacional[i].value);
    }
    console.log(soma); }
```

Comment: Por que você inicializou `soma` com um array? Não deveria ter inicializado com 0?

Comment: Além disso, de onde veio a variável `nacional`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alguns problemas a ter em conta:

- `[]`é uma array, para juntar items/valores, deves usar um numero para poderes somar.
- `parseInt` deve usar-se com o radix, ou seja com `10` como segundo argumento. Eu prefiro usar `Number()`.

Um exemplo do que queres fazer pode ser assim:

```js
var nacional = document.querySelectorAll(".soma-nacional");

function somatoriaNacional(inputs) {
  return [...inputs].reduce((soma, input) => soma + Number(input.value), 0);
}

var somaNacional = somatoriaNacional(nacional);
console.log('Soma:', somaNacional);
```

```html
<form class="nacional">
  <input class="soma-nacional" value="5">
  <input class="soma-nacional" value="3">
  <input class="soma-nacional" value="2">
</form>
```

O teu código corrigido seria assim:

```js
var nacional = document.querySelectorAll(".soma-nacional");



function somatoriaNacional() {
  var soma = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < nacional.length; i++) {
    soma += Number(nacional[i].value);
  }
  return soma;
}

var somaNacional = somatoriaNacional(nacional);
console.log('Soma:', somaNacional);
```

```html
<form class="nacional">
  <input class="soma-nacional" value="5">
  <input class="soma-nacional" value="3">
  <input class="soma-nacional" value="2">
</form>
```