# Somar vários inputs

Tags: javascript, html

Poderiam por gentileza me ajudar?

Estou tentando fazer uma função que some vários inputs, porém ao invés de somar está concatenando.

**HMTL**

```
<form class="nacional">
    <input class="soma-nacional" value="5">
    <input class="soma-nacional" value="3">
    <input class="soma-nacional" value="2">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var nacional = document.querySelectorAll(".soma-nacional");
var somaNacional = [];

function somatoriaNacional(){
    var soma = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < nacional.length; i++){
        soma += parseInt(nacional[i].value);
    }
    console.log(soma); 
}
```

Comment: Edite a **[pergunta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/441159/problema-em-somar-varios-inputs)** para que ela possa ser reaberta...

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você inicializou a variável `soma` com um *array*, quando deveria inicializar com um número (no caso o número zero). Veja abaixo como deveria ficar o seu código:

```
function somatoriaNacional(){
    var soma = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < nacional.length; i++){
        soma += parseInt(nacional[i].value);
    }
    console.log(soma); 
}
```